# Angular2 Observable with interval

Tags: javascript, angular, intervals, rxjs, observable

I have a function that needs to be called about every 500ms. The way I am looking at doing it with angular2 is using intervals and observables. I have tried this function to create the observable:

```
counter() {
  return Observable.create(observer => {
    setInterval(() => {
      return this.media.getCurrentPosition();
    }, 500)
  })
}
```

With this code for the subscriber:

```
test() {
  this.playerService.initUrl(xxxx) // This works
  this.playerService.counter().subscribe(data => {
    res => {
      console.log(data);
    }
  })
}
```

I am very new to observables and angular2 so I might be taking the wrong approach completely. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `Observable` class has a static `interval` method taking milliseconds (like the `setInterval` method) as a parameter:

```js
counter() {
    return Observable
        .interval(500)
        .flatMap(() => {
            return this.media.getCurrentPosition();
        });
}
```

And in your component or wherever:

```js
test() {
  this.playerService.initUrl(xxxx) // This works
  this.playerService.counter().subscribe(
      data => {
          console.log(data);
      }
   );
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks! I did have to change the `.flatmap()` to `.flatMap()` to make it work correctly though.

Comment: just a note for others; `Observable.interval` is a static/class method, you cannot call it on an instance of Observable (I ran into an issue with this in angular when trying to repeat an `http.get`)

Comment: `Observable.interval()` is now deprecated not the preferred way of creating such an observable. The preferred way of doing this is via the IntervalObservable or TimerObservable. [ currently in Typscript 2.5.2, rxjs 5.4.3, Angular 5.0.0 ]

Comment: @Gokul do you have any sources for that?